# Find duplicate records from a grid that has 20,000 records without any access to DB fastly

Tags: java, c#, search-engine

In my test automation I do not have access to XML or database.I want to find the duplicate records for a particular column in the grid. My grid has 20,000 records.The only issue is we do not have access to any database so it is slow if I change the page, each page loads 50 records.There is performance issue with 20,000 records.

Comment: I suggest you fix the performance issues, 20K record is not that big these days.  You can use an simple in memory data structure provided to you to speed it up.  I can't give more details without you including some details.  The data structures in the JVM works fine into the tens of millions of records.  If you need hundreds of million or billions there is in memory database solutions, but you are a long way from needing them.

Comment: I am using java to write the code to get duplicate records in the grid. But the issue is number of records. Could you please describe the logic

Comment: How do you detect if a record is duplicated?

Comment: What is your performance requirement? Are you caching your results so you don't recalculate them on ever page access?

Comment: Why  java **and** C#?

Comment: I need to test if one of the column has duplicate data or not using java and selenium . The test is to put a assertfalse if there is a duplicate. I am not getting how to write this as we do not have access to database. We are using the records in the UI.

Comment: Each time the page loads 50 records.We have multiple pages for 20,000 records. It does not matter even if someone reply in C#

Comment: @user3285912 see my answer showing you can do this in 2 ms, or less if you cache the result. I am still not clear how fast you need it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have generated this result, you would cache this so it doesn't have to be regenerated on each page access.  However at 2 milli-seconds, you might not bother.

Here is an example with timing

```
static class MyRecord {
    String text;
    int id;
    double d;

    public MyRecord(String text, int id, double d) {
        this.text = text;
        this.id = id;
        this.d = d;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int t = 0; t < 100; t++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Random rand = new Random();
        Map<Integer, MyRecord> map = IntStream.range(0, 20000)
                .mapToObj(i -> new MyRecord("text-" + i, rand.nextInt(i+1), i))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyRecord::getId, 
                        Collectors.reducing(null, (a, b) -> a == null ? b : a)));
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Took %.1f ms to generate and collect duplicates%n", time/1e6);
    }
}
```

This test takes 2.0 ms to generate and sort out duplicate records.  You can write the same code in Java 7, it would just be longer to write but it wouldn't be any slower..  If it didn't have to generate the records it would be faster.

For comparison, I made it concurrent with

```
Map<Integer, MyRecord> map = IntStream.range(0, 20000).parallel()
    .mapToObj(i -> new MyRecord("text-" + i, rand.nextInt(i+1), i))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(MyRecord::getId,
            Collectors.reducing(null, (a, b) -> a == null ? b : a)));
```

but it now takes 16 ms. :P

Answer (score 0):

Create a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<YourObject>>` - each time you got the same object by the object Id put it in the map by it's and add it to the ArrayList

Comment: HaspMap and list are not that fast

Comment: You can either use HashTable

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor A Hashtable wouldn't be faster

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic option. For demonstration purposes I created a list with 20,000+ records, and then check for duplicates in it - resulting in 29 milliseconds.

Basically, the idea is to scan your values, and for each value verify it is unique - if it is, put it in the "unique" bucket against which you compare; otherwise - put it in the duplicates bucket.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


public class FindDuplicates {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<String>();

        values.add("1");
        values.add("2");
        values.add("3");

        for(int i=0;i<=20000;i++)
        {
            values.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }

        values.add("1");
        values.add("2");
        values.add("4");

        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for(String str : values)
        {
            if(unique.contains(str))
            {
                duplicates.add(str);
            }
            else
            {
                unique.add(str);
            }
        }

        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Processing time: " + (after-before));

        System.out.println("total values: " + values.size());
        System.out.println("total unique: " + unique.size());
        System.out.println("total duplicates: " + duplicates.size());
    }

}
```